# JS: orientationchange before?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, rotation

the orientationchange fires after the rotation has been completed. how can i fire a event before the os starts the integrated window rotation ?

edit: eg. to fade out elements before rotation starts

Comment: may I ask where you want to use it for, that might help for a solution

Comment: ok-i've re-edited my question

Comment: don't think that's possible to do unless you use the NDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can detect the devices precise rotation so when you see it rotates to a precise point, before the screen rotates, you can trigger it.

This may have some false positives tough.
http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source-orientation.html

Answer (score 1):

I have made jQuery plugin beforeorientationchange, it will work on iOS & Android (default browser, not Chrome)

https://github.com/evaldsurtans/jquery.beforeorientationchange